# Copy existing file into new directory using PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

Struggling with why my code isn't working. I'm ultimately trying to copy an entire directory, but settled with just copying one file for now since the "while loop" function is still above my understanding. I would definitely appreciate some assistance. Here's what I have for now. I'm simply creating a folder with the username I got from the form. I just don't know how to copy files from another existing folder. I checked to see if there was something similar here, but didn't quite find anything.

```
<?php
$folder = "/";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$thisdir = getcwd();
$folderPath = $thisdir . $folder . $name;
$source = "index.html";
$desitination =  $folderPath;
copy($source, $desitination);
if(!file_exists($folderPath)){
  mkdir($folderPath);
  chmod($folderPath,0777);
}

?>
```

Comment: What the os do you use? Is it windows or unix like environment?

Comment: Ok, but what Operating System?. The directory separator in windows are "\" and in Linux/Mac OS X are "/". That could be the one the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using OS X.

Comment: Use the PHP constant : `$folder = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`

Comment: I greatly appreciated the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy function in php accept two names and not only directory.

So instead

```
copy("file1.txt", $folderPath)
```

do

```
copy("file1.txt", $folderPath . "/file1.txt")
```

and use error feedback to understanding better

```
if (copy("file1.txt", "folder1/file1.txt")) {
    echo "File Copied";
} else {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "File not copied, " . $errors["messages"];
}
```